# Ruby 1.8 vs 2.3 handling YAML config arrays differently

Tags: yaml, ruby-2.3

I'm trying to upgrade a server that has ruby scripts developed by another person. I'm a perl/php developer and no little about ruby, just trying to get the scripts to work that was developed with Ruby 1.8 and the scripts seems to behave differently handling arrays in the newer version. The script was not matching iterated folders with a config file array with the folder names and I believe I've boiled it down to the way the YAML config file is converted to an array. I put together this simple script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yaml'
config_filename = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/testruby.yml")
@config = YAML.load(File.open(config_filename))
puts @config
```

The YAML testruby.yml config file looks like this:

```
1_01:
  name: Monday Show
  suffix: showM
  program_id: 123
  segment: 1
  dated: false
1_02:
  name: Monday Show
  suffix: showM
  program_id: 123
  segment: 2
  dated: false
1_03:
  name: Tuesday Show
  suffix: showT
  program_id: 124
  segment: 1
  dated: true
```

When I run this on the original server with Ruby 1.8, the result is:

```
1_03program_id124nameTuesday Showsegment1suffixshowTdatedtrue1_02program_id123nameMonday Showsegment2suffixshowMdatedfalse1_01program_id123nameMonday Showsegment1suffixshowMdatedfalse
```

But when ran on the new server with Ruby 2.3 I get a array:

```
{101=>{"name"=>"Monday Show", "suffix"=>"showM", "program_id"=>123, "segment"=>1, "dated"=>false}, 102=>{"name"=>"Monday Show", "suffix"=>"showM", "program_id"=>123, "segment"=>2, "dated"=>false}, 103=>{"name"=>"Tuesday Show", "suffix"=>"showT", "program_id"=>124, "segment"=>1, "dated"=>true}}
```

It even removes the underscore from the folder name key in the config file. For this reason, later in the script, calls to `@config[1_01]` does not match of course. Is there a way to get the array to build like version 1.9 so the rest of the script works as designed?

One more thing to note, not sure if it related to the issue. The `require 'yaml'` line was not present in the script, I added after receiving this error when ran:

```
testruby.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant YAML (NameError)
```

Comment: Same array result when using `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems all I had to do was enclose the YAML keys in quotes and now the hash object includes the underscore in the keys and the rest of the script works!